# Glide get image cache list

Tags: android, performance, android-glide

here the scenario

1: Open android app with glide, then glide download the image and save it in cache.

2.if app is close then reopen, then the URL is same, glide load the image from cache

3:While not connecting to internet,when open the app, i want to make glide display random image from cache, it will be nice if glide can list all the URL from cache

how to make step 3 work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`DiskCacheStrategy`**](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/420/com/bumptech/glide/load/engine/DiskCacheStrategy.html).

> Set of available caching strategies for media.

**`static DiskCacheStrategy ALL`**

> [**`Glide`**](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) uses memory and disk caching by default to avoid unnecessary
>   network requests.

```
Glide.with(contextOBJ)
 .load("IMAGE_LINK")   
 .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
 .into(imageViewOBJ);
```

Comment: you know i dont get the link, after all you not answering my question

Comment: where to get list of cache from glide, not how to use glide

Comment: i ask how to get cache list not how to use glide.

Comment: @MuhammadAimanBinKamal https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/965 ,https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/411, 
 https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/509